# I cannot randomize my list. it gives me only one character when I print it

Tags: python, random

```
#Password Generator Project
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

password = []

for l in range (0 , nr_letters+1):
    random_l = random.choice(letters)
    password.append(random_l)

for i in range (0 , nr_symbols+1):
    random_i = random.choice(symbols)
    password.append(random_i)

for n in range (0 , nr_numbers+1):
    random_n = random.choice(numbers)
    password.append(random_n)

print(random.choice(password))
```

I want to randomize and print the password list at the end of the code but it gives me only one character. When I print it without random function or shuffle it prints properly.

Comment: Don't use `random.choice(password)`. Use `random.shuffle(password)`

Comment: *password* is a list (a sequence). random.choice selects a single pseudo-random item from a sequence. Thus you get just one character. Also, take a look at random.choices for a means to eliminate your loops

Comment: Side note: strings are symbol arrays, no need to put them in lists. In ranges, 0 is inclusive and can be omitted, `''.join(random.choice(numbers) for i in range(n_numbers))` is a more common way to express this. Also, take a look at `string` and `secrets` modules: first one regardless; second one if it is not a purely training project.

Answer (score 2):

In OP's question *password* is a list (a sequence). *random.choice()* selects a single pseudo-random item from a sequence. Thus you get just one character.

Using *random.choices()* simplifies the entire process

```
from random import choices, shuffle
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

symbols = '!#$%&()*+'

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")

nr_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password? "))
nr_symbols = int(input("How many symbols would you like? "))
nr_numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like? "))

password = choices(ascii_lowercase, k=nr_letters)
password += choices(digits, k=nr_numbers)
password += choices(symbols, k=nr_symbols)

shuffle(password)

print(''.join(password))
```

**Example:**

```
Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!
How many letters would you like in your password? 6
How many symbols would you like? 2
How many numbers would you like? 2
bf%t6vf(g0
```

Comment: This is the best answer imo. Didn't know about the k in choices.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice(password)` just picks a random item from `password`. Use `random.shuffle(password)` to shuffle it.

```
random.shuffle(password)
print("".join(password))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changes made**

```
(1) you are taking one character extra in each of them.. Corrected!
(2) created a variable res_in_str which is string storing the password generated
(3) created a variable res_in_list which is list storing the password generated in list format
```

**Code:-**

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

password = []

for l in range (0 , nr_letters):
    random_l = random.choice(letters)
    password.append(random_l)

for i in range (0 , nr_symbols):
    random_i = random.choice(symbols)
    password.append(random_i)

for n in range (0 , nr_numbers):
    random_n = random.choice(numbers)
    password.append(random_n)
res_in_str=""
res_in_list=[]
while len(password):
    char=random.choice(password)
    password.remove(char)
    res_in_str+=char
    res_in_list.append(char)
print("Password Generated: ",res_in_str)
print("Password Generated in list format: ",res_in_list)
```

**Output:-**

```
Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!
How many letters would you like in your password?
6
How many symbols would you like?
3
How many numbers would you like?
3
Password Generated:  ZIL!0cy#r25#
Password Generated in list format:  ['Z', 'I', 'L', '!', '0', 'c', 'y', '#', 'r', '2', '5', '#']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code**

Your code is correct down to the last row in the `print` function.

Instead, you should use the `join` string method like this :

```py
print(password)
# ['s', 'F', 'h', 'i', 'b', 'f', '*', '$', '(', '&', '(', '$', '4', '4', '6', '2', '4', '2']

# So you could use for instance the join function combined with
# random to reconstitue a readable randomized password
print(''.join(random.sample(password, k=len(password))))
# s$($b4(24&2Fhf64*i
```

The fact is that, by using the `choice` function in the `print` row, you ask for returning a unique randomized letter from your password.

**My proposal**

Indeed, I proposed you the following code instead :

```py
from random import sample
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits

symbols = '!#$%&()*+'

nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

agg_s =  sample(ascii_uppercase, nr_letters)
agg_s += sample(symbols, nr_letters) # or string.punctuation instead symbols
agg_s += sample(digits, nr_numbers)

password = ''.join(sample(agg_s, k=len(agg_s)))

print("password : " , password)
# password :  9E6XC%P&$24J1(!
```

**Note :**

Taking a same length randomized sample from a sample is equivalent to a randomized permutation.
So no matter if the variable agg_s is followed by letters, and then respectively by symbols and digits.
When you are using `sample(k, len(k))` to reorganize agg_s, you effectively have a randomized password.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve it:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation
from random import choice, shuffle
def selector(quantity, type):
    return(return([choice([x for x in type]) for _ in range(0, quantity)]))
print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= selector(int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")), ascii_letters)
nr_symbols = selector(int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n")), punctuation)
nr_numbers = selector(int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n")), digits)
temp_password = nr_letters+nr_symbols+nr_numbers
shuffle(temp_password)
password = "".join(temp_password)
print(password)
```

Results:

```
Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!
How many letters would you like in your password?
8
How many symbols would you like?
4
How many numbers would you like?
2
1IEa>L'cBSR_^9

Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!
How many letters would you like in your password?
8
How many symbols would you like?
0
How many numbers would you like?
6
bJOV06DR340Y4S
```